# Set font and size on Android app

Tags: android

I want set my global application desired font and size 
this is what im done :

1.copied my ttf font to my assets\fonts\1.ttf
2.set my app default font :

```
 public static Typeface setmyfont(){
         return  Typeface.createFromAsset(getAppContext().getAssets(), "fonts/1.ttf");
 }
```

3.using my predifiend font :

```
txtbox1.setTypeface(AppContext.setmyfont());
```

4.then set size for all global font with creating "Theme" ins "Style.xml" :

```
<style name="Theme" parent="@style/System">
        <item name="android:textSize">20.0sp</item>
```

5.and set it in my manifest :

```
<application android:theme="@style/Theme" ...
```

now the defult font changed for my app , and some of theme have applied size
but other still using default application size.
how can i fix the other fonts ?

Comment: Check your layout's `TextViews`. If you have specified `android:textSize` in the layout then remove it.

Comment: Make sure you put your theme customizations in all of the values/themes. There's theme.xml in values-v11 and values-v14 I believe